# NextJS import location styling?

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, coding-style

I have already a project which has a file that is importing following function

```
import theme from 'src/configs/theme'
```

But when i created new **nextjs** project and created same folder structure and imported same function it is saying module not found, it works if i change it to

`import theme from '../../configs/theme'`, is there any thing i m missing?  The above one looks more clean and clear

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer, i had to just add

```
"baseUrl": ".",
```

in `compilerOption` of tsconfig.json file